# New to programming and I cant seem to figure out how to disable a powerup in the game I am making

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am most likely going about this the wrong way so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The problem I am having is that when I pick up the power up my lasers turn to the correct shot but then don't switch back after a certain amount of time. Any idea how or why its not getting rid of my supershot buff?

```
   private void Fire()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        if (ActivateSuperShot)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DisableSuperShotPowerup());
            superShotFiringCoroutine = StartCoroutine(SuperShotFireContinuously());
        }
        else
        {
            firingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FireContinuously());
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        StopCoroutine(firingCoroutine);
        StopCoroutine(superShotFiringCoroutine);
    }
}


IEnumerator SuperShotFireContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        FireSuperShot();
    }
 }



IEnumerator FireContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        FireNormalLaser();
    }
}

IEnumerator DisableSuperShotPowerup()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(powerupTime);
    ActivateSuperShot = false;
}

//Activate PowerUp in seperate Script

    if (player != null)
            {
    switch (powerupID)
    {
        //0= shield  1= speed  2=SuperShot
        case 0:
            player.ActivateShield();
            break;
        case 1:
            player.ActivateSpeed();
            break;
        case 2:
            player.ActivateSuperShot = true;
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Invalid Powerup");
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd expect the line `StartCoroutine(DisableSuperShotPowerup());` to occur in the same place as `ActivateSuperShot = true;`  but that never seems to occur. Is `ActivateSuperShot` ever set to `true`? Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did my best to make it more minimal reproducible. ActivateSuperShot is set to true on powerup pickup in a separate script. I have added that code to the question.

Comment: What happens if you add a method to `Player`: `public void DoActivateSuperShot(){ActivateSuperShot = true; StartCoroutine(DisableSuperShotPowerup());}`, replace in `SeparateScript` the line `player.ActivateSuperShot = true;` with `player.DoActivateSupershot();` and finally remove the  `StartCoroutine(DisableSuperShotPowerup());` line from `Fire`?

Comment: That seemed to fix my main issue!! I got a few more kinks I need to work out like supershot doesnt stop as long as I am holding down the fire button. Once I lift the fire button it stops. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of beginning the coroutine that stops the powerup on input, have it begin when the powerup is activated:

```
bool activateSuperShot;

private void Fire()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        if (activateSuperShot)
        {
            superShotFiringCoroutine = StartCoroutine(SuperShotFireContinuously());
        }
        else
        {
            firingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FireContinuously());
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        StopCoroutine(firingCoroutine);
        StopCoroutine(superShotFiringCoroutine);
    }
}


IEnumerator SuperShotFireContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        FireSuperShot();
    }
 }

IEnumerator FireContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        FireNormalLaser();
    }
}

IEnumerator DisableSuperShotPowerup()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(powerupTime);
    activateSuperShot = false;
}

public void ActivateSuperShot() 
{
    activateSuperShot = true;    
    StartCoroutine(DisableSuperShotPowerup());
}

//Activate PowerUp in seperate Script

    if (player != null)
            {
    switch (powerupID)
    {
        //0= shield  1= speed  2=SuperShot
        case 0:
            player.ActivateShield();
            break;
        case 1:
            player.ActivateSpeed();
            break;
        case 2:
            player.ActivateSuperShot();
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Invalid Powerup");
            break;
    }
}
```

note: in C# code, fields are typically `camelCase`.